# Resteasy paths JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, url, jboss5.x, resteasy

I am having trouble navigating to my restful service using resteasy 2.1 on localhost and was hoping someone here might be able to help me.

I have built an EAR file with a WAR inside and is seems to compile and deploy to JBoss5 ok.

My service simplified:

```
@Path("RequestReply")
public class Replier {

    @GET
    @Path("request")
    public String getReply(@QueryParam("id") @DefaultValue("") String id){
            if (id.length > 0){
                return "ACK";
            }
            return "NACK";
        }
}
```

My web.xml file is standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app>
    <display-name>Test service</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

So I try to access my API using

> http://localhost:8080/RequestReply/request?id=1234

But I get 404 errors.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <application xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"; version="5"> 

        <display-name>Reseasy</display-name> 

        <module> 
            <java>simple.jar</java> 
        </module> 

    </application>
```

Comment: I had an issue with this when I first started using Resteasy. Have you registered your context-root in your application.xml file?

Comment: I have an application.xml file but not sure how exactly how to use it. Have I missed some settings?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
             version="5">

    <display-name>Reseasy</display-name>

    <module>
        <java>simple.jar</java>
    </module>

</application>

Comment: Ok I see what's going on here you are missing web context info... What does simple.jar refer to?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure. I got the file from another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I would suggest trying something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
             version="5">

    <display-name>Reseasy</display-name>

    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>Replier.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/api</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>

</application>
```

Here the Replier.war refers to the name of the WAR file you create and /api refers to the base of your request URL. So it should look like:

> http://localhost:8080/api/RequestReply/request?id=1234

Give that a shot!